# Matlab optimization routines failing to fit simple sinusoidal data

Tags: matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, sine-wave

I have some simple time vs position data that I am trying to fit using any of matlab's optimization functions. I've given an example of the data (shown in blue) and the sinusoidal fit I am getting when using lsqnonlin (shown in red). [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DUPe.png)

I know my fits are somewhat sensitive to the initial conditions, but I also know the amplitude of my data are very close to ~1 and the frequency is very close to 6 Hz. Despite using initial guesses close to the actual values, the curve-fitting only works on approximately 1 out of every 3 curves I try to fit. Why could something like this be happening?

For reference, here is the function I have written which is getting optimized (Note: my data already has mean=0 so I don't need an offset term):

```
    function [err,pred] = sine_fit2(k,x,y)
            pred = k(1)*sin(2*pi*x./k(2))+k(3)*cos(2*pi*x./k(2));
            err=(y-pred);
    end
```

I've tried a few different optimization functions in matlab, including: lsqnonlin, lsqcurvefit, fminsearch, fminunc

I've also played around with the initial conditions (IC) and found that, for example, curve A might be fit well with IC#1, but not with IC#2, whereas curve B is fit poorly when using IC#1, but fit well when using IC#2, etc.

Seeing as the data is pretty clean, I'm really surprised the optimization routines are not able to find the correct parameters. Maybe I am doing something really silly! Any help/explanations are much appreciated

EDIT (11/6/2017 @7:30AM)
Here is how I am calling my optimization:

```
% initial guesses
k0 = [1,1/6,1]; 

% y = data I'm trying to fit
% t = independent variable (time)
[k_opt] = lsqnonlin(@(k)sine_fit2(k,t,y),k0,[],[],lsq_options);
[error,prediction] = sine_fit2(k_opt,t,y);
```

Also, here is an example of the data I'm trying to fit (note that I multiplied y by 100 to get more significant figures to display):

```
    t       y*100

      0    0.1225
 0.0435   -0.0698
 0.0870   -0.0550
 0.1304    0.0410
 0.1739   -0.0908
 0.2174   -0.1034
 0.2609    0.0671
 0.3043    0.0044
 0.3478   -0.0630
 0.3913    0.1045
 0.4348    0.1177
 0.4783   -0.0324
 0.5217    0.0332
 0.5652    0.0886
 0.6087   -0.0767
 0.6522   -0.0867
 0.6957    0.0586
 0.7391   -0.0534
 0.7826   -0.1024
 0.8261    0.0948
 0.8696    0.0441
 0.9130   -0.1001
 0.9565    0.0114
 1.0000    0.0457
```

Comment: What is the scale on your plot?  It can't be seen in the image you link to.  Also, give examples for your x and y data, and an example of how you are calling the optimizers.

Comment: Hey Phil, the y-limits on the graphs are [-2e-3,2e-3]. Just added some example data and the code for how I'm calling the optimization